# Use superior predictive ability (SPA) test in R

Tags: r, matlab

Does anynoe know hot to use the SPA test in R/Matlab or other software; it is a statistical method to evaluate models. I knew that there is a R package called "ttrTests"  has a relevant SPA function, but it looks like suitable for comparing portfolio strategies, rather than comparing general models in terms of some loss function. Can someone tell me other source or how to prepare the data suitable for the "ttrTests" package.

Comment: This github repo https://github.com/cran/ttrTests seems useful. See e.g. https://github.com/cran/ttrTests/blob/master/R/dataSnoop.R. Unfortunately the library seems orphaned.

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps because it really depends on what question you're trying to answer with your data, but there is a method called Model Confidence Set which selects a set of statistically equally good models according to a loss function and is implemented in the 'MCS' package.

Answer (score 0):

The [Model Confidence Set](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.8504.pdf) package tests multiple models for superior predictive ability.

```
install.packages("MCS")
library(MCS)
data(Loss)
MCS <- MCSprocedure(Loss=Loss[,1:5],alpha=0.2,B=5000,statistic='Tmax',cl=NULL)
```

...and the output:

```
> MCS <- MCSprocedure(Loss=Loss[,1:5],alpha=0.2,B=5000,statistic='Tmax',cl=NULL)

###########################################################################################################################
Superior Set Model created  :
             Rank_M        v_M  MCS_M Rank_R         v_R  MCS_R         Loss
sGARCH-norm       4  0.8201805 0.6034      4  1.43408052 0.3576 0.0004042581
sGARCH-std        5  0.9649670 0.5008      5  3.22834167 0.0058 0.0004010655
sGARCH-ged        1 -1.3942903 1.0000      3  0.21893448 0.9940 0.0003986329
sGARCH-snorm      2 -1.3101987 1.0000      2  0.08452883 0.9998 0.0003982803
sGARCH-sstd       3 -0.4739630 1.0000      1 -0.08452883 1.0000 0.0003977886
p-value :
[1] 0.5008

###########################################################################################################################
>
```

Comment: I wonder the explanation of the output of the MCS procdure. I can't find any source that briefly tell the out of the MCS procedure. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at the [MFE Toolbox](https://www.kevinsheppard.com/MFE_Toolbox) for Matlab. It includes two distinct multiple hypotesis tests that may be helpful for you:

- Model Confidence Set (`mcs` function)
- Reality Check and Test for Superior Predictive Accuracy (`bsds` function)

The framework is pretty well documented and you can see these implementations from [this page](https://github.com/bashtage/mfe-toolbox/tree/master/bootstrap).